# Using the Scope Resolution Operator in Laravel

Tags: php, oop, laravel

I'm confused about an aspect of OOP/Laravel.

I'm following an OOP tutorial (nothing to do with Laravel) that states that you can only use the Scope Resolution Operator when the method you are calling is **static**.

So I created a quick script;

```
class Student { 
  function welcome_students($var="Hello") {
    echo "{$var} students.";
  }  
}
echo Student::welcome_students("Greetings") ."<br />";
```

And I get the error;

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method Student::welcome_students() should
not be called statically in /static_modifier.php on line 11 Greetings students.
```

But in Laravel 5, I've noticed that I've been using calls like

```
`ClassName::whereIn($var = `
```

in quite a few of my Controllers. I've checked the package where the `whereIn` method is stored and it's not `static`. It's just a `public function`.

So how is Laravel 5 allowing me to get away with it? I'm in development mode so I don't know why I'm not seeing that same message.

Comment: make your function a public static at the moment its just a public function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some fairly advanced concepts here that need to be understood in order to fully grasp how this is happening.

First, this would only work for the facades in Laravel.  These can be found in the `app.php` config file in the aliases array.  Each of these facades can be thought of as entry points for their real classes which are in the Laravel core.  So even though the syntax is telling you that you are calling static methods, what's really happening is Laravel is resolving the underlying classes to these proxy classes and calling methods non-statically on those.

You can see this better if you go to some of those facade classes where you will see the methods you are calling are not actually present on those classes.

To really understand how this is happening, read up on Laravel's inversion of control container (IoC), its use of Facades, and the php magic method `__callStatic`, and the php method `class_alias` which is what Laravel is using to setup the aliases.

Again, these are fairly complex concepts so don't get discouraged if they seem confusing or the purpose eludes you.

Basically, the workflow looks like this...

1. You call Config::get()
2. Laravel looks up the alias for Config which is a facade.
3. Using the __callStatic magic method, the facade figures out the underlying class to instantiate and calls the appropriate method on that non-statically.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/facades#explanation

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc#introduction

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic

Comment: So what you're saying is... When I do `ClassName::whereIn(..` in Laravel, I'm not referring directly to the `whereIn` method at `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php` but I'm actually going to it via a facade?

Comment: That's correct, you would be referring to the facade but only if there is a facade.  If you are calling a class that is not a facade like that, I imagine it will still give you the warning.  This is why all the aliases in app.php are pointing to a facade.

Comment: `Eloquent` isn't pointing to a Facade in mine but I think I get your overall point. I will read up more on Facades. I'm sure there is a good reason.. But having just noticed this, it looks like a way of cheating/getting around PHP in a way you're not meant to.

Comment: I believe `Eloquent` is pointing to `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` for the sake of convenience in your models.  You just extend `Eloquent` rather than `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` when creating a new model.  In this case, most of the methods in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` are static.

Comment: `Eloquent` or rather `Model` is not a Facade but does some very similar things with `__callStatic` to first instanciate a new model (instance of itself) and then call the method.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your function is not static, you need change it  if you want to call it like `Student::welcome_students()`

```
public static function welcome_students($var="Hello") {
    echo "{$var} students.";
  }
```

Comment: Yeah.. I did that on purpose to show it would get that warning. But the same thing doesn't happen in Laravel. Hence my confusion

Comment: @mike3875 user3158900 said that Laravel used Facades for static accessing, which return name of registred class_alias in IoC .